# Nasm x86 Assembly - Error ‘comma, colon, decorator, or end of line expected after operand’

Tags: string, assembly, x86, nasm

I have just started in nasm x86 Assembly and I just cannot figure out why I get this error:

```
main.asm:9: error: colon, comma, decorator, or end of line expected after operand
```

On this line:

```
mov [msg], db ‘Hello World’
```

Anyway thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't move a string into memory in one instruction.  Are you trying to get `msg` to contain a pointer to the string, or are you trying to actually copy the string there?

Comment: An assembler isn't a compiler: you can't just put arbitrary-length string literals wherever you want.  The assembler won't invent anonymous space in `.rodata` for your string data and use its address in the immediate for that store instruction.  Also, the operand-size is ambiguous; I hope you wanted to store a `dword` pointer to `msg: resd 1` in the BSS (C equivalent `char *msg;`), not actually memcpy to a whole array.